# Make WPF window always in front of another process's window via HWND?

Tags: wpf, windows, winapi

I am in control of two windows in different processes and I would like to enforce that window B is always in front of window A.  Window B is always created after window A.  The two processes are communicating within a plugin architecture, so it's possible to send messages both ways.  In this particular case, Window B is WPF and Window A could be WPF, MFC, or WinForms.  So I'm guessing a lowest common denominator HWND-based solution will be needed.

Currently I'm setting Window B to TopMost.  This is acceptable, but it would be better if other windows besides A were allowed to sit on top of B.

Comment: This fails the "What if someone else did this" test. What if the other process' window decides that it wants to be in front of yours?

Comment: That is a very good point.  I actually own both of the windows and I'm using an interprocess plug-in architecture.  I have the freedom to do it the other way - the "in front" window can send its HWND to the other window.  I will update the question to reflect this.

Comment: This is not easily doable. Natively there are only regular windows, sorted by Z-order, and topmost windows. A window is always in front of another window if they have an owner-owned relationship. While you can create this relationship across threads (and processes), it is non-trivial to implement.

Comment: I read that on Raymond Chen's blog... I thought there might be some way to do it other than owner/owned.

Comment: I wouldn't know of an easy solution. A possible route would be to handle `WM_ACTIVATE` and change the Z-order of window B (`SetWindowPos`) if required. This may cause window A to temporarily obscure B - not entirely aesthetic. Another possibility would be to respond to [WinEvents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373889.aspx) instead, [`EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318066.aspx) looks promising, but may suffer from the same effect, and temporarily cover window B.

Comment: It's easy to _implement_ (just set the WPF Window.Owner property), but has [*very* nontrivial implications](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/04/12/10410454.aspx)  - namely, the thread input queues are now attached.  I'd lean towards using the WinEvents model, or just stick with topmost.

Comment: Hey IInspectable, if you make an answer out of your comments I will accept it.